# Records navigation

Tags: c#, sql-server, navigation

Using C# and SQL server, I want to be able to navigate through the records. Should I load all records into the dataset? Database could become very large. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How large?  This is the kind of useful information that would help us in giving you a decent answer.

Comment: Is it web or desktop application?

Comment: How about using a query to achieve only the relevant data?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 1):

It is always a **good habit to navigate around the records using pagination**. Because memory is the issue. You should not load a large amount of data in your memory... So, pagination is the solution

How to do the **custom pagination** in your gridview control check this [Pagination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx) and [Custom Pagination](http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/03/30/custom-paging-in-asp-net-gridview-control/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You shold use custom pagination and by that you and get the number or record you want ...to achieve this use can make use of grid view and cutompaging sp in your sql server**

checkt this : [ASP.NET Extended Grid Control](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-extended-grid-control.html)

EnhanceGrid which has the following features:

- Custom paging to fetch only the required number of records
- Icon in the header of the column to display sorting direction
- Dropdown in the pager to adjust the number of records in a page
- Properties of the extended grid
- How to use the custom grid control

[image]